# Inserting VBA formula into a defined Range

Tags: excel, insert, vlookup, vba

I'm looping through a table (Sheet4) in a worksheet and inserting an empty column between each original column.  In the new, empty columns, I want to insert a VLookup function.

I has successfully inserted the columns and I have successfully held the proper range (proper number of rows too) in a variable called FormulaRange.

I'm having problems with the VLookup. I don't know if it's the way I'm storing my variables or if I need to have a paste function after my Vlookup. Can someone take a look and give me a hand? 
*note - I stored FormulaRange as String becuase As Range wouldn't let me pass my code into the variable. As a result I can't use the FormulaRange.Formula Method.

If I were to manually input the VLookup I would write it as =VLOOKUP(B1,RosettaStone_Employees!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE) and then copy down the range.

```
    Sub InsertColumnsAndFormulasUntilEndOfProductivityTable()
    Dim ActivityRange As Range
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim FormulaRange As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim Startrow As String
    Dim Lastrow As String

    Sheet6.Activate
    Set ActivityRange = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Sheet4.Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    y = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    x = (Sheet4.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) * 2

    For i = 1 + 2 To x Step 2
        Columns(i).EntireColumn.Insert
            Startrow = 2
            Lastrow = y
            UserName = Cells(1, i - 1)
            FormulaRange = Cells(Startrow, i).Address & ":" & Cells(Lastrow + 1, i).Address
            FormulaRange = "=VLookup(UserName, ActivityRange, 2, False)"

    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: I haven't tries it but it should be something like this.....`"=VLookup(" & UserName, ActivityRange & ", 2, False)"`

Comment: Davesexcel's response is close.  @Jonh you will be inserting the text in for each cell in the loop.  So, you will need to enter:

    "=Vlookup(" & UserName & ", " & ActivityRange & ", 2, FALSE)"

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: By using just ActivityRange it will try to put the value in the formula where what is needed is a range.  Also using the string of UserName value would no longer the formula to be dynamic. That last part may be what the OP wants and it will work in the formula so it is up to the OP.

Comment: Thanks guys,  I used Scotts answer from yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little to get rid of the sheet activates.  Also I changed a few things to ranges and included with blocks.

This is untested:

```
Sub InsertColumnsAndFormulasUntilEndOfProductivityTable()
Dim ActivityRange As Range
Dim UserName As String
Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim Startrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

With Sheet6
    Set ActivityRange = .Range("A1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
End With
With Sheet4
    y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    x = (.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) * 2

    For i = 1 + 2 To x Step 2
        .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Insert
        Startrow = 2
        Lastrow = y
        UserName = .Cells(1, i - 1) 
        Set FormulaRange = .Range(.Cells(Startrow, i), .Cells(Lastrow + 1, i))
        FormulaRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R1C[-1],'" & ActivityRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & ActivityRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2, False)"
        'If you do not want dynamic formulas and just want the value 
        'then comment out the above and use the below.
        'FormulaRange.Value = Application.Vlookup(UserName,ActivityRange,2,False)
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

The `R1C1` is a relative nomenclature.  When it fills the formulas into the columns it will return the cell relative to the one into which the formula will be filled.

For example, above I use `R1C[-1]`.  This says get the first row of the column directly to the left.  So if the formula was being entered into `B2` it would return `A$1`.

The `[]` denotes the relative address.  Without the `[]` eg `R1C1` it would indicate an absolute address and would return `$A$1`.  So `R1C1:R4C2` would return a range of `$A$1:$B$4`.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your help. Some of the tips in your code are great ("With Sheet4" vs activating Sheet4.)

I'm still getting an error however. "Object doesn't support this property or method". Do you know why this might be?

Comment: What line is highlighted?

Comment: Hold on guys and gals... I'm on to something! I'll get back to you when I figure it out... very exciting stuff :)

Comment: Sorry Scott... to answer your question it's this line:  

FormulaRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(R1C[-1],'" & ActivityRange.Parent & "'!" & ActivityRange.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ", 2,

Comment: @Jonh figured out the problem.  See edit.  Forgot the `.Name` on the parent

Comment: @Jonh glad I could help.  Please consider marking as correct.